# Как определить элемент из другой активити? (Android)

Tags: mediaplayer, activity, android, java, исключения

Есть активити -  Main и сервис - wRef;
В wRef есть плеер, громкость которого нужно менять из Main.
Делаю так:

---

```
public wRef wr;
wr = new wRef();
```

И немного ниже:  
    wr.player.setVolume(20, 20)

---

В результате меня выкидывает из приложения с исключением NullPointerException. Как я понял, в Main не определён плеер из wRef. Как его определить или что ещё можно сделать?

Comment: Верно ли я понимаю, что вы пытаетесь запустить сервис банальным `new wRef()`?

Answer (score 1):

правильно NullPointerException выкидывает, при переходе с текущей activity на wRef, текущая уничтожается 
 в один момент времени может быть запущена только одна activity
возможно я неправильно понял задачу, но этот подход изначально не верен, как писали раньше используйте сервис

Comment: @gadfil, значит я неправильно задал вопрос.wRef является сервисом, а Main - это активити

Comment: > при переходе с текущей activity на wRef, текущая уничтожается 
>
> в один момент времени может быть запущена только одна activity

Хм. Это вы откуда такого понабрались?

Comment: действительно, не всегда соответствует истине, но нельзя гарантировать что объект Activity и связанные с ним объекты находятся в памяти, когда Activity приостановлено или завершено    
если не прав поправьте, будет интересно и полезно и мне и топикастеру  
сам не проверял, но знакомый утверждает что при переходе на новую Activity срабатывает сборщик мусора (не могу дать ссылку на первоисточник, это его практические наблюдения)

Comment: Может быть вы всё-таки мне поможете?)

Comment: мы и вправду отошли от темы, хотя ответ @falstaf был бы очень интересен (ни в коем случае не ирония, я прекрасно понимаю что пробелов у меня хватает) 
сама идея примерно такая
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305407/how-to-design-activity-service-interaction-for-a-simple-mp3-player     
и не wr = new wRef(); (на это ранее обратил внимание @falstaf  ) попробуйте работать через ServiceConnection
http://www.startofandroid.com/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/162-urok-97-service-binding-serviceconnection.html
http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/163-urok-98-service-lokalnyj-binding.html

Comment: Рекомендую всё же заглянуть в документацию: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html и http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html — там немало примеров, обильно сдобренных комментариями. И обратите внимание на секцию *Starting a Service*.